# how to start operating system on a Samsung SSD when old hard drive was broken so had to replace

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, ssd

Recently went into Apple with my early 2011 MacBook Pro, was told that my hard drive was broken. So I decided to replace it myself with a Samsung 850 EVO, all went okay, but now when I turn it on all I get is a file with a question mark in it.

I couldn't upload anything to the SSD before installing as my Mac wasn't working at all and had a white screen with a spinning wheel. I had no new operating system on my Mac as I hadn't updated it in a while. A CD came with the drive but my laptop is having none of it it just turns on to a white screen with the mouse on it.

As you can see I'm not very technical so if any responses could be dulled down a bit that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get it online (for example, with an Ethernet cable), all you have to do is hold command-R at startup to enter recovery mode and install the OS over the Internet. You can also use it to format the disk if needed.

http://www.techradar.com/us/how-to/computing/apple/how-to-fix-mac-boot-up-problems-in-recovery-mode-1305641